# control should go to other program on exit in if statement using php

Tags: php, if-statement, exit

i have 2 programs welcome.php and form.jsp.  i am tyring to insert values into SQL database using odbc through user form. i have created a userform using form.jsp. inserting rows using welcome.php. while insertion am not inserting duplicate values so that am checking conditions in while loop. when the if statements are working, it's completely come out from the program due to exit() statement. after execution of exit am getting blank page. but i need to stayback to the user form or the control should go to form.jsp so that again i should get the user form to enter the details without giving blank page.how can i do this?

```
        $query1="select * from company";
        $result1 = odbc_exec($connect, $query1);

         while(odbc_fetch_row($result1)){
         $compname[$index] = odbc_result($result1, 1);
         $empname[$index] = odbc_result($result1, 2);

        if($compname[$index]==$_POST['cname'])
        {
       echo "<script> alert(\"compname Exists\") </script>";
       exit();
       //exit("<script> alert(\"compname Exists\") </script>");
       }
       if($empname[$index]==$_POST['ename'])
       {
      echo "<script> alert(\"empname Exists\") </script>";
      exit();
     }
     }
     $query=("INSERT INTO dbo.urllink(cname,ename) VALUES ('$_POST[cname]','$_POST[ename]') ");
     $result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);
    echo "<script> alert(\"Row Inserted\") </script>";

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `exit()` stops the processing of the program. To send the user to another page from PHP, you can use the `header()` function, with the 'Location: ' parameter:

```
header('Location: form.jsp');
```

Note that you cannot output information (using `echo` for example) and then use the `header` function. All output will need to be done by the page your sending them to.

If you want to pass information, like a submitted field exists, you can send it using a query string parameter, for example:

```
header('Location: form.jsp?error=abc');
```

Your JSP page would then display an error depending on what `abc` meant.

Alternatively, you can use sessions to pass more complex information to another page.
You can find more info on sessions [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Comment: Note that you can also make use of session data to avoid needing to pass a bunch of data back via the URL.

Comment: should i write function for abc??

Comment: @Akshara, If you're going to use the error parameter in the query string, you need to put some code into your JSP that will extract the value ('abc') from the query string and display a message depending on that value. E.g. abc could mean 'Compname exists' whereas xyz could mean 'Empname exists'.

Comment: Something along the lines of `String error = request.getParameter("error");` Then you just print out the error variable in your JSP code.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of output buffering and the header function.

```
ob_start();
... many lines of code ...
header("Location: reload.php");
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

You can also use javascript for that.

```
window.location = "your location path where you want to redirect";

                     OR

window.location.href = "your location path where you want to redirect";
```

i think this may also helpful to you.

Thanks.